# standardjs throws 'Blob' is not defined

Tags: javascript, standardjs

I have this code

```
const blobData = new Blob([url])
```

and when I run standard js it throws "'Blob' is not defined"

Someone have an idea why it's happening?

Comment: standard.js is a node module, your not trying to run this in browser are you?

Comment: No, I'm trying to apply it on my frontend (react) code in CI

Comment: frontend is the browser end.  IOW: Blob is only available Server Side, unless you used a polyfill,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use Blob inside your browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob. To resolve this lint issue you have to configure your eslint config like this:

in **package.json**:

```
...
"standard": {
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  }
},
...
```

or in **.eslintrc**:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  ...
}
```